# Using '&&' operator for angular validation in thymeleaf

Tags: angularjs, thymeleaf

I'm a little unaware on why thymeleaf doesn't accept few cases.

I have this validation in my html page:

```
<input id="republish" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
       ng-click="doRepublish()" value="Republish" disabled="disabled"
       ng-disabled="!republishInput && republishInput.length < 7"/>
```

Whenever there is a '&&', the thmeleaf throws this exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow
>   the '&' in the entity reference.

I have checked in this [github post](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/611) that:

> Thymeleaf 2.1 uses an XML parser to process your template (v3.0 uses
>   an HTML one, and this would not happen). So the XML parser does not
>   know that the contents of your `<script>` should be processed as
>   `CDATA` (i.e. ignored) and finds that your `&&` is indeed invalid HTML
>   (it thinks it is an escape code).
>
> The solution is to wrap your JavaScript code with `<![CDATA[...]]>`,
>   like:
>
> ```
> <script>
> // <![CDATA[
>    ...your code here
> // ]]>
> </script>
> ```
>
> That way you'll make the `CDATA` section explicit and the XML parser
>   will understand that it does not have to worry about what is inside
>   that block.

But this seems to be for a xml. How could I collaborate with my `ng-disabled`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know thymeleaf but maybe you can try encoding the special values in HTML :

```
<input id="republish" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
       ng-click="doRepublish()" value="Republish" disabled="disabled"
       ng-disabled="!republishInput &amp;&amp; republishInput.length &lt; 7"/>
```

Although I would recommend to replace this by a call to a function defined in your controller, something like:

```
<input id="republish" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
       ng-click="doRepublish()" value="Republish" disabled="disabled"
       ng-disabled="!canRepublish(7)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you ssougnez.